# Can't get my custom odoo module to appear

Tags: python, django, odoo, odoo-8

I'm very new to odoo and python and was wondering if I could get some help getting my module to load. I've been following the odoo 8 documentation very closely and can't get anything to appear in the local modules part. (Yes, I have clicked refresh/update module list).

I have also made sure that I put the correct path in my odoo-server.conf file and ensured their are no clashes.

Below is the code:

```
Models.py




    Created on 4 Sep 2015

@author: 
'''
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api

# class test(model.Model):
#     _name = 'test.test'

#     name = fields.Char()

__init__.py

        from . import controllers
    from . import models

__openerp__.py file

    {
    'name': "models",
    'version': '1.0',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'author': "Elliot",
    'category': 'Category',
    'description': """
    My first working module.
    """, 
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'data': [
        'templates.xml',
             ],
    'xml': [
             'xml.xml'
             ],
}

controllers.py

    from openerp import http

    # class test_mod(http.Controller):
    #     @http.route('/test_mod/model/', auth='public')
    #     def index(self, **kw):
    #         return "Hello, world"

    #     @http.route('/test_mod/model/objects/', auth='public')
    #     def list(self, **kw):
    #         return http.request.render('test_mod.listing', {
    #             'root': '/Test_mod/Test_mod',
    #             'objects': http.request.env['test_mod.model'].search([]),
    #         })

    #              @http.route('/test_mod/model/objects/<model("test_mod.model"):obj>/', auth= 'public')
    #     def object(self, obj, **kw):
    #         return http.request.render('test_mod.object', {
    #             'object': obj
    #         })
    and templates.xml

<openerp>
        <data>
        <!-- <template id="listing"> -->
        <!--   <ul> -->
        <!--     <li t-foreach="objects" t-as="object"> -->
        <!--       <a t-attf-href="{{ root }}/objects/{{ object.id }}"> -->
        <!--         <t t-esc="object.display_name"/> -->
        <!--       </a> -->
        <!--     </li> -->
        <!--   </ul> -->
        <!-- </template> -->
        <!-- <template id="object"> -->
        <!--   <h1><t t-esc="object.display_name"/></h1> -->
        <!--   <dl> -->
        <!--     <t t-foreach="object._fields" t-as="field"> -->
        <!--       <dt><t t-esc="field"/></dt> -->
        <!--       <dd><t t-esc="object[field]"/></dd> -->
        <!--     </t> -->
        <!--   </dl> -->
        <!-- </template> -->

        </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have missed to include the addon directory which includes the custom module.

It can be accomplished via two methods.

1. You can add to, the addons_path directive in openerp-server.conf, (separate paths with a comma)

   ```
   eg: addons_path = /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons,custom_path_here
   ```
2. You can use

   ```
   --addons='addon_path',
   ```

   if starting your server from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your service (odoo-service).